# docker build invalid tag

Tags: git, docker

I'm trying to tag my docker image with the git branch name.
I have this error: "invalid argument ... for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format"

I converted branch name to lowercase but I still have this issue.

This is the error:

```
invalid argument "dockdgsp01:5000/lmr_controller_channel_plan:20201009-4131043-feature/pk-2631-implement-dwell-time-logic-in-the-lmr-controller" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
```

where:

- name: lmr_controller_channel_plan
- date: 20201009
- githash: 4131043
- git branch: feature/pk-2631-implement-dwell-time-logic-in-the-lmr-controller

What is the error here?
What are valid names (strings) for a docker tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your problem it the "/" between feature and pk.

If you are calling the command from a bash script you can try removing it like this:

```
variable=${variable//"/"/-}
```

Supposing that variable contains the string "feature/pk-2631-implement-dwell-time-logic-in-the-lmr-controller"

And then use it in your docker command as `$variable`

Comment: while this is a good solution to solve the problem, I would not recommend it since it might create issue with similarly named branches. e.g. `fix/anchors` and `fixanchors` will create the same docker tag.

Comment: How come? fix/anchors will became fix-anchors fixanchors will remain the same. On the other hand, feature/blabla or fix/blabla are examples of gitflow convention, if you stick to it i don't see the problem. Maybe i'm missing something?

Comment: it depends on what you replace with what. in my example I just removed the / but I could have replaced it with -. imho this is a problem (if you work on large projects)

Comment: Ok, so you don't see a problem in replace it with a "-" as in my example?

Comment: no, absolutely. my point is simply that if you have `fix/api/with-huge-hammer` and `fix/api-with-huge-hammer` will produce the same tag (fix-api-with-huge-hammer).

Comment: btw there was a missing / in the replace. the original command would have replaced only the first instance and left the rest as it is.

Answer (score 3):

From the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/):

> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.

In other words, you cannot use '/' in the docker tag. I suggest to use the git commit hash instead (even though it's not that fancy).